# Google FIT API Request not working - no data returned

Tags: android, kotlin, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

My Goal: I wanted to retieve my Step Counter data from Google FIT API with a small Android App. Therefore I tried the tutorial code:

1. I implemented the log in code which is necessary to use Google FIT (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)
2. Then I implemented the Google Fit request for the historical step counter data (https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history)
3. I granted access to the FIT API for my app.

My Problem:
The code seems to work properly. The successListener is called but there is no data retrieved. What am I doing wrong?

My Code (sorry, it' copy paseted from the tutorial, not formated, not properly):

```
class GoogleFitStepCounterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 123456

    private val RC_SIGN_IN = 1

    private var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient? = null

    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    var gso: GoogleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val signInButton = findViewById<SignInButton>(R.id.sign_in_button)
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD)

        signInButton.setOnClickListener {
            signIn()
        }


        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
        updateUI(account)
    }

    private fun updateUI(account: GoogleSignInAccount?) {
        if (account != null)
        {
            this.requestGoogleFITData()
        }
    }

    private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient!!.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode === RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> =
                GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try {
            val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)

            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            updateUI(account)
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
            updateUI(null)
        }
    }

    fun requestGoogleFITData()
    {
        var fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .build()

        val account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions)

        if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, fitnessOptions)) {
            GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this, // your activity
                GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE, // e.g. 1
                account,
                fitnessOptions)
        } else {
            accessGoogleFit()
        }
    }


    private fun accessGoogleFit() {
        val end = LocalDateTime.now()
        val start = end.minusYears(1)
        val endSeconds = end.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond()
        val startSeconds = start.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond()

        val readRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setTimeRange(startSeconds, endSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .build()

        val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .build()

        val account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions)
        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, account)
            .readData(readRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener({ response ->
                // Use response data here
                //Log.i(TAG, "OnSuccess()")

                // The aggregate query puts datasets into buckets, so flatten into a
                // single list of datasets
                for (dataSet in response.buckets.flatMap { it.dataSets }) {
                    dumpDataSet(dataSet)
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(
                {
                        e -> Log.d(TAG, "OnFailure()", e)
                })
    }


    fun dumpDataSet(dataSet: DataSet) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: ${dataSet.dataType.name}")
        for (dp in dataSet.dataPoints) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Data point:")
            Log.i(TAG,"\tType: ${dp.dataType.name}")
            Log.i(TAG,"\tStart: ${dp.getStartTimeString()}")
            Log.i(TAG,"\tEnd: ${dp.getEndTimeString()}")
            for (field in dp.dataType.fields) {
                Log.i(TAG,"\tField: ${field.name.toString()} Value: ${dp.getValue(field)}")
            }
        }
    }

    fun DataPoint.getStartTimeString() = Instant.ofEpochSecond(this.getStartTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDateTime().toString()

    fun DataPoint.getEndTimeString() = Instant.ofEpochSecond(this.getEndTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDateTime().toString()
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @cb9980 Same issue here. Any luck with it since?

Comment: Make sure 

Make sure to allow users to use the OAuth in GCP console. Go to Google Cloud Platform > Apis & Services > OAuth consent screen and check if your app is in Testing mode and add gmails to allow user to use the Oauth. Also SHA-1 must be configured. 

See 
https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started
https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-api-key?hl=en